# How can I split this string with random whitespace delimiters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm extracting table information from a log file and the expected result is a csv file with 4 fields.

The table entries in the log file are separated by whitespaces. However, some of the table entries are sentences so using `str.split()` cant be used. Also, some of the table entries are separated by only 1 space.

I have already tried `str.split()` and `re.split(r'\s{2,}', line)` but the entries on the 4th field get split into numerous cells cause of the entries being sentences

```
with open(openfile) as datafile:
    for line in datafile: 
        if command in line:
            for line in datafile:
               if endcommand in line:
                    break
               else:
                    splitted = re.split(r'\s{2,}', line)
                    wr = csv.writer(resultFyle, dialect='excel')
                    wr.writerow(splitted)
```

Expected results are:

```
['Serial0/0','Up','Up','This leads to somewhere']
```

Actual results are:

```
['Serial0/0','Up','Up','This', 'leads', 'to', 'somewhere']
```

Comment: what is `command`?

Comment: the command is a string I use to scan the log file to get the information I want

Comment: You can use the string split method but provide a `maxsplit` argument, assuming that your data are consistent with your example there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, if the data is persistent you may use the `maxsplit` argument.

```
splitted = re.split(r'\s{2,}', line, 3)
```